# Call Of Duty API - How can I get a list of all user platforms by entering username only?

Tags: python, api

I'm trying to use the Call of Duty API, I am forced to put the platform in the call like in the example below:

```
https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/{title}/platform/**{platform}**/gamer/{gamer}/profile/type/{gamemode}
```

I need a link that return a *list of users* and platforms by inserting only the **username**.

It should be seems like this:

```
https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/{title}/gamer/**example**/profile/type/{gamemode}
```

and the Output should be like:

```
[
username: example#12345
platform: psn

username: example
platform: battle

username: example#56789
platform: xbl

username: example#13579
platform: uno

etc..]
```

I know that already exists an api to do this but I can't find it!

Answer (score 0):

They actually don't allow this anymore since the api update and overhaul. You must authorize yourself and csn only check your own